# My blogger url-based openid stopped working

Tags: support, openid, login

I had a working url-based openid from blogger, but I can no longer log in to SO with that identity. I get an error on the Google side "The requested URL /accounts/TokenAuth... is too large to process." Probably not an SO problem, but does anyone know the cause or a workaround? I'm not ready to change identities :-).

Comment: I get this too occasionally. Seams to depend what machine i'm using and weather conditions... :(

Answer (score 2):

This is because Blogger is a poor implementation of an old version of OpenID.  StackOverflow is sending longer URLs now than it used to -- still legal, but Blogger can't handle it.

See my post for how you can fix it for yourself, without changing identities:
[How to upgrade your Blogger OpenID to a decent one](http://blog.nerdbank.net/2010/03/how-to-upgrade-your-blogger-openid-to.html)

Answer (score 2):

Today I also received the following error:

> "414 Request-URI Too Large" 
>   The requested URL /accounts/TokenAuth... is too large to process.

As a quick workaround, try logging into the blogger.com account first and then try to login to stackoverflow.

Comment: your workaround works for me

Answer (score 0):

This happened when I changed my blog theme to dynamic view. When I switched to classic it started working again.